# Display a base64 encoded image to HTML without making a GET request to the server

Tags: javascript, html, image, socket.io, base64

I have an image on the server. I am using Socket.io to read that PNG image every 5 seconds. I am converting the image to base64 and then sending the base64 string to client. The code is below:

```
var imageUpload = function(){
    fs.readFile('image1.png', 'base64', function(err, buf){
      socket.emit('image upload', { image: true, buffer: buf });
      setTimeout(imageUpload, 5000);
    });
  };
```

On client side, I get the data from socket and then call function displayImage() which displays the base64 image to html page.

```
var displayImage = function(data){
    var URL = 'data:image/png;base64,'+data.buffer;
    document.querySelector("#uploaded-image").src = URL;
  }
```

But the problem is, it makes a GET request to server for the image every time.

As I am sending the image as a base64 string, is there some way to just display that string as an image without making a GET request because it doesn't makes sense to send the file and then again request for the same file through GET?

> PS: I am working on a project where I want a live video stream. As I
>   cannot get a video stream, I am working with the live images generated
>   by the research camera in a buffered loop. I want to display that
>   images in a 50 millisecond interval so it looks like a live video
>   stream. So I just want to send that bunch of images from server
>   continuously without making a GET request.

Comment: Can you tell from the dev tools whether socket.io or the browser/renderer is making those get calls?

Comment: Yeah from dev tools(Network tab in chrome) I can tell that. As the socket.io sends the string and when I change the src of image, my browser issues a GET request.

Comment: What is the url for the get request? Can you post some more data?

Comment: The URL is quite big. You can see that here - http://pastebin.ca/3660910 . Also just open this web address and see the console and network request - https://socket-hello-world-pranjalsingi.c9users.io/

Comment: So it's just making a `GET` request to your base64-url, the request isn't going to your server. It's just making the request because you gave it a URL, which happens to have all the data in it.

Comment: Yeah I see that now. Thanks soo much. Can you provide me some insight. Is there a better way to do what I am trying to do? Please see PS.

Comment: Why not just cache the base64? Declare a variable somewhere, and anytime you want to display the image simply use that variable. If the variable has not been assigned it, send the `GET` request to retrieve the base64 and save it to the variable first.